# Python 3 multiple inheritance __init__ second class

Tags: python, initialization, multiple-inheritance

in Python3 i have one class that inherits two other classes.
However as i see when an object is initialized only first class of it initialized also see example...

```py
    class A:
        def __init__(self):
            print("A constructor")


    class B:
        def __init__(self):
            print("B constructor")


    class C(A, B):
        def __init__(self):
            print("C constructor")
            super().__init__()


    c = C()
```

This has the output:

> C constructor 
>   A constructor

My questions are, why it does not call B constructor also?
And is it possible to call B constructor from C class with super?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print("A constructor")
        super().__init__()        # We need to explicitly call super's __init__ method. Otherwise, None will be returned and the execution will be stopped here.

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        print("B constructor")


class C(A, B):
    def __init__(self):
        print("C constructor")
        super().__init__()        # This will call class A's __init__ method. Try: print(C.mro()) to know why it will call A's __init__ method and not B's.

c = C()
```